# How to send message in my profile with python

Tags: python, autologin, tampering

I know my question may be is not really good. but as a person who is new with python I have a question:

I wrote a code with python that make me login to my page:

```
import urllib, urllib2, cookielib

email = 'myuser'
password = 'mypass'

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
login_data = urllib.urlencode({'email' : email, 'password' : password})
opener.open('http://test.com/signin', login_data)
resp = opener.open('http://test.com/dashboard')
print resp.read()
```

and now I an connected to my page....

This is my tamper data when I want to send message to site:

How can I send hello with python now?
could you possibly complete the code and tell me how it is done?

## UPDATE

I changed my code like so:

```
import requests

url1 = 'http://test.com/signin'
data1 = {
    'email': 'user',
    'password': 'pass',
    }
requests.post(url1, data=data1)

url2 = 'http://test.com/dashboard'
data2 = {
    'post_temp_id': '61jm5by188',
    'message': 'hello',
    }
requests.post(url2, data=data2)
```

But no result

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Although you could start off using `urllib`, you'll be happier using `requests`. How to use the POST method:

```
import requests
resp = requests.post('http://test.com/dashboard', data={'post_temp_id': '61jm5by188', 'message': 'hello'})
```

Pretty simple, right? Dictionaries can be used to define headers, cookies, and whatever else you'd want to include in your request. Most requests will only need a single line of code.

EDIT1: I don't have a test.com account, but you may try using this script to test out the POST method. This [website](http://hroch486.icpf.cas.cz/formpost.html) will echo what you submit in the form, and the script should get you the same response:

```
import requests
resp = requests.post('http://hroch486.icpf.cas.cz/cgi-bin/echo.pl',
                     data={'your_name': 'myname',
                           'fruit': ['Banana', 'Lemon', 'Plum']})
idx1 = resp.text.index('Parsed values')
idx2 = resp.text.index('No cookies')
print resp.text[idx1:idx2]
```

From the HTML you received, here's what you should see:

```
Parsed values</H2>
<UL>
<LI>fruit:
<UL compact type=square>
<LI>Banana
<LI>Lemon
<LI>Plum
</UL>
<LI>your_name = myname
</UL>
<H2>
```

EDIT2: How to use a session object:

```
from requests import Session
s = Session()
# Don't just copy this; set your data accordingly...
url1 = url2 = data1 = data2 = ...
resp1 = s.post(url1, data=data1)
resp2 = s.post(url2, data=data2)
```

The advantage of a session object is that it stores any cookies and headers from previous responses.

Comment: But when I add this line to my code it doesn't work...could you possibly tell me how to correct the code? thank yoiu

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, do you mean that you didn't get a response? When you use the `post` method, a `Response` object is returned. Store it (as I did in my example) and look at the status code (`resp.status_code`). You also might want to take a look at the [reference pages](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/). Hope this helps.

Comment: yes...It returns 200 to me... Is my update code true?

Comment: It doesn't post hello word on be half of me in test.com

Comment: Hmm. I'm not familiar with test.com, but you might need to add appropriate headers or cookies. I'd suggest using a `Session` object to log in instead of the plain `requests.post`. You can read about it [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects).

Comment: Thank you ... I would check